# PHP. Почему увеличивается пиковое значение используемой памяти при очистке переменных и массивов?

Tags: php, оптимизация, память, переменные

Я проводил оптимизацию производительности в своих PHP скриптах с помощью unset-ов.

К примеру:

```
$a=mysql_query("SELECT etc");
 while($b=mysql_fetch_assoc($a)){
     //do some
}
unset($a);
```

Оказалось, то при каждом unset($a) у меня уменьшается значение, выдаваемое memory_get_usage() (не сюрприз), но при этом растёт значение пикового потребления памяти скриптом, выдаваемое memory_get_peak_usage()

Вот так я вводил новые unset-ы в скрипт:

```
$log->LogDebug('MemUsage (after all) '.(memory_get_usage()-$base_memory_usage).'. Memory peak was '.memory_get_peak_usage(TRUE).'.');
```

и получал данные о потребляемой памяти в логе с каждой итерацией:

```
MemUsage (after all) 281080. Memory peak was 559024.
MemUsage (after all) 275008. Memory peak was 576728.
MemUsage (after all) 274608. Memory peak was 579024.
MemUsage (after all) 274272. Memory peak was 786432.
```

Не очень понятно, почему при удалении массивов и переменных пиковое использование памяти скриптом растёт. Я ожидал, что оба значения будут уменьшаться, так как считал, что пиковое значение memory_get_peak_usage(TRUE) - это максимальное значение memory_get_usage()

Comment: PHP5? Попробуйте под 7.

Answer (score 0):

Первое, что нужно знать об unset - это то, что он не очищает память мгновенно. Вызов данной функции просто помечает переменные для удаления, а сборщик мусора сделает это, когда посчитает нужным. Это значит, что память сразу не очистится, а очистит ее только сборщик мусора.

Как работает сборщик мусора можно прочитать [тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/features.gc.php) и более детально как работает unset [тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.references.unset.php).

Второй момент - это то, что mysql_query возвращает тип resource. 
unset($a) очищает ресурс, а не массив.

Comment: Это не объясняет, почему растет пиковое потребление, даже если явно вызывать сборку мусора. И почему под РНР7 оно не растёт.

Comment: @Ипатьев возможно такой эффект потому, что php7 выделяет память кусками, а не по запросу как в php5.